# Testing in solidity with npm not work correctly?

Tags: solidity, mocha

I have a problem like this. I am new to solidity development. I have created a contract like this.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
     address[] public players;

    function Lottery() public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter() public payable { 

        require(msg.value > 0.1 ether);
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }


    function random() public  view returns (uint) {

     return   uint(keccak256(block.difficulty,now,players));//hashing
    }

  function pickWinner() public restricted{
      uint index = random() % players.length;
      players[index].transfer(this.balance);
      players = new address[](0);
  }

  modifier restricted(){

      require (msg.sender == manager);
      _;
  }

  function getPlayers() public view returns (address[]) {
      return players;

  }

}
```

This is my Test js file is like this.

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');//we are importing a constructor function so capittalize
//Instance 

const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
const { interface, bytecode } = require('../compile');



let accounts;
let lottery;
beforeEach(async ()=>{
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    lottery =await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
        .deploy({ data: bytecode })
        .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000'});
});


describe('Lottery', ()=>{
    it('deploys a contract',()=>{
        assert.ok(lottery.options.address);//check is there a value or not
    });

    it('allows account to enter', async()=>{
        await lottery.methods.enter().send({
            from: accounts[0],
            value: web3.utils.toWei('0.02', 'ether')
        });

        const players = await lottery.methods.getPlayers().call({
            from: accounts[0]
        });

        assert.equal(accounts[0],players[0]);
        assert.equal(1, players.length);

    })
});
```

When I hit npm run test it gives me an error like this.

```
   √ deploys a contract
    1) allows account to enter


  1 passing (318ms)
  1 failing

  1) Inbox
       allows account to enter:
     i: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
      at Function.i.fromResults (node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\lib\utils\runtimeerror.js:91:1)
      at C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\slv\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\lib\blockchain_double.js:539:1
      at C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\slv\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\async\internal\once.js:12:1
      at p (node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\async\internal\eachOfLimit.js:61:1)
      at C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\slv\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\async\internal\eachOfLimit.js:71:1
      at a.default (node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\async\eachLimit.js:43:1)
      at C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\slv\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\async\internal\doLimit.js:9:1
      at v.r.emit (node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\async-eventemitter\lib\AsyncEventEmitter.js:42:1)
      at C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\slv\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\dist\runBlock.js:52:1
      at C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\slv\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\dist\runBlock.js:174:1
      at C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\slv\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\dist\cache.js:110:1
      at C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\slv\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:473:1
      at d (node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1006:1)
      at C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\slv\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1016:1
      at Da (node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3196:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1046:1)
      at C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\slv\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\dist\cache.js:106:1
      at C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\slv\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:969:1
      at n (node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:5225:1)
      at C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\slv\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\dist\cache.js:103:1
      at n (node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:5223:1)
      at C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\slv\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\dist\cache.js:103:1
      at n (node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:5223:1)
      at C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\slv\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\ethereumjs-vm\dist\cache.js:98:1
      at C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\slv\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\merkle-patricia-tree\util.js:51:1
      at C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\slv\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\merkle-patricia-tree\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:1
      at f (node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\merkle-patricia-tree\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:246:1)
      at C:\Users\tharindusa\Desktop\slv\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\merkle-patricia-tree\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:44:1
      at Immediate._onImmediate (node_modules\ganache-cli\build\webpack:\ganache\node_modules\ganache-core\node_modules\levelup\lib\levelup.js:286:20)



npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! inbox@1.0.0 test: `mocha`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the inbox@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tharindusa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-04T05_52_38_807Z-debug.log
```

I search for a solution but I was unable to find a suitable solution. So can someone help me to solve this problem? Thankyou!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In function `enter` you require `msg.value > 0.1 ether`, but then you call it with  `0.02 ether`.

So the test does exactly what it's supposed to do - revert this function call.